# What is faster, lock or Thread.Interrupt?

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking

I have a program that involves receiving a packet from a network on one thread, then notifying other threads that the packet was received. My current approach uses Thread.Interrupt, which seems to be a bit slow when transferring huge amounts of data. Would it be faster to use "lock" to avoid using to many interrupts, or is a lock really just calling Interrupt() in its implementation?

Comment: There are so many places where you can find advice against using Exceptions for "normal" control flow in an application. Which to my mind, would rule `Thread.Interrupt` out in the first place.

Comment: The question though; is an exception being thrown internally within a "lock", thus making the two equivalent?

Comment: Neither a lock nor `Thread.Interrupt` seem like a sensible way to achieve communication or synchronization between threads. I'm not even sure how you'd be thinking of using a lock in this scenario. But I'm fairly certain I can answer the last question raised - I don't believe that lock uses `Thread.Interrupt` internally at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you would use `Thread.Interrupt` rather than some more traditional signalling method to notify waiting threads that data is received.  `Thread.Interrupt` requires the target thread to be in a wait state anyway, so why not just add an object that you can signal to the target thread's wait logic, and use that to kick it for new data?

`lock` is used to protect critical code or data from execution by other threads and is ill-suited as a mechanism for inter-thread active signalling.

Use `WaitOne` or `WaitAll` on suitable object(s) instead of either.  `System.Collections.Concurrent` in .Net 4 also provides excellent means for queueing new data to a pol of target threads, and other possible approaches to your problem.

Comment: I must be missing something in your design.  If target threads are ready to process new data, they could wait on some object and get the notification immediately (this is not a state variable poll, as you seem to think?).  If your target threads are not in the correct state to process new data, what is the value of a 'drop everything, here is new data' signaling approach anyway?

Comment: Looked up the documentation for WaitHandle and it looks like it should work pretty well.

Comment: Steve and Brian are not suggesting that you poll anything.  The wait functions are blocking and will return 'immediately' if signaled appropriately. Also, if a packet needs to be signaled to a thread, it's 'traditional' to receive the packet into an allocated struct/class instance and transfer the pointer/refernce only.  The 'transferring' then takes the same time no matter how much data is involved.

Comment: @IDWMaster - `WaitHandle` is often a superclass of the synchronization objects that @Brian Gideon listed - pick your poison from that list, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Thread.Interrupt` and `lock` are not well suited for signaling other threads.

- `Thread.Interrupt` is used to poke or unstick one of the blocking calls in the BCL.
- `lock` is used to prevent simultaneous access to a resource or a block of code.

Signaling other threads is better accomplished with one the following mechanisms.

- [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) (or [ManualResetEventSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx))
- [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)
- [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx)
- [Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx)
- [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx)
- [WaitHandle.WaitAny or WaitHandle.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a standard queue and the lock keyword when reading or writing it.  Alternatively, the Synchronized method on the queue removes the need to use lock.  A System.Threading.Semaphore is the best tool for notifying worker threads when there is a new job to process.

Example of how to add to queue

```
lock ( myQueue) { myQueue.Enqueue(workItem); }
mySemaphore.Release();
```

Example of how to process a work item:

```
mySemaphore.WaitOne();
lock (myQueue) { object workItem = myQueue.Dequeue(); }
// process work item
```

Semaphore setup:

```
mySemaphore = new Semaphore(0, int.MaxValue);
```

If this is too slow and synchronization overhead still dominates your application, you might want to look at dispatching more than one work item at a time.

Depending on what you're doing, the new parallelization features in .NET 4.0 may also be very helpful for your application (if that's an option).

Comment: As others have mentioned, Thread.Interrupt is odd and non-standard.  I've actually never heard of it until now and I've done multi-threading in .NET for years.  If you're going for easy-to-maintain code that is easily understood, the above examples don't get much simpler.

Comment: Yup. That's exactly how I've been doing inter-thread comms for decades.  Some form of 'lock()', 'semaphore.signal' and 'semaphore.wait' are available in every OS I've ever used.  As soon as you go any lower, looking at lock-free queues, interlocked exchanges, condvars etc. things start to get platform/CPU/OS dependent :(